# Removing the 'and' from between two authors, revtex4-1

Tags: titles, affiliation

Basically I'm trying to separate multiple authors names using a comma instead of 'and', here's what I'm doing...

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,a4paper,twocolumn,superscriptaddress,notitlepage]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\author{Thing One}
\author{Thing Two}
\affiliation{Working here}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Which at the moment prints `Thing One and Thing Two`, instead of spacing them by a comma... `Thing One, Thing Two`. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I've gone ahead and inserted the instruction `\maketitle` immediately before `\end{document}` in order for your MWE to produce some output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fairly quick solution to your issue consists of inserting the instruction

```
\def\andname{,} % default: \def{andname}{and}
```

in the preamble. (Revtex's `\maketitle` routine executes the macro `\andname` when it joins exactly two authors' names.) However, this leaves quite a bit of whitespace between the superscript marker following the first author's name and the comma. A somewhat improved look is achieved by setting

```
\def\andname{\hspace*{-0.5em},}
```

instead.

Comment: @Mico, could you help me? For my own reasons I need to substitute ", and" by "e". Using `\def\andname{e}` I get ", e". How do I get rid of the comma?

Comment: @fcpenha - I experience no odd behavior (i.e., no spurious comma) when I set `\def\andname{e}` as the last instruction of the preamble, i.e., immediately before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @Mico, I get the last comma even when choosing `\def\andname{}`.

Comment: @Mico The solution to my problem is adding `\def\andname{e}` `\def\@listcomma@comma{\@ifnum{\@tempcnta>\tw@}{,}{}}`. If I understood it correctly, it says that the comma should be put when there are more than two elements left.

Answer (score 0):

Can somebody please help me figure out how to remove the comma ' , ' right before the 'and' that is automatically put before the last author? I am using revtex, and I basically do not want any commas automatically added after author names in the title (not the bibliography). How can I just remove these commas?
Thank you!

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/229353)