# Removing 'and' in the author list

Tags: titles, affiliation

I'm trying to remove 'and' before the name of the last author in the title of the article (class `llncs`) so that it would look like `First Author, Second Author, Third Author` instead of `First Author, Second Author, and Third Author`.

I found a fix here [Removing the 'and' from between two authors, revtex4-1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48407/removing-the-and-from-between-two-authors-revtex4-1) (the suggestion was to use `\def\andname{,}` in the preamble), but it doesn't apply to my case (and I actually checked - it didn't work), since my code looks like this

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}    
\author{
First Author\inst{1}
\and
Second Author\inst{1}
\and
Third Author\inst{2}
}
\institute{
Institute A\\
\email{\{user1,user2\}@domain.tld},\\
\and
Institute B\\
\email{user3@domain.tld}
}
\maketitle
```

Is there any way to remove 'and'?

Comment: I bet Springer will revert any changes to the title  ;-)

Comment: `\renewcommand{\lastandname}{\unskip,}`

Comment: @Johannes_B You should make that an answer

Comment: @AndrewSwann Finally done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is quite simple if you know where to look for it.

`\renewcommand{\lastandname}{\unskip,}`

Comment: Can you also show us where to look for it?

Comment: @bkarpuz In the class/package source.

Answer (score 1):

Another command that I found useful is the following:

```
\renewcommand\Authand{}
```

Check [the authblk documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/preprint/authblk.pdf), it may help:

Comment: `llncs` uses its own interface for author and affiliation.